# git deployment running under IIS

Tags: iis, git

I have a Bonobo git server installed on a Windows Server 2016.
It is deployed in IIS and accesible on url myserver/git.
Next I want to enaeble automatic deployment.
In the Git Server bare repository folder I find the hooks folder and add a post-receive script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd E:/public/root/myFirstRepo
git pull
```

This works fine when I run it as my personal user. But when its used by IIS after a commit it gives:

> git: 'pull' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Am I using the correct git?

```
#!/bin/sh
git --exec-path
```

> Personal user: C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core
>
> IIS user: /libexec/git-core

So lets change the script to use an absolute git path:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd E:/public/root/myFirstRepo
"C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git" pull
```

> fatal: Not a git repository: '.'

This might be because im already in a git repo, namely the bare server repo and it might confuse git? So lets try to ignore any present enviroment.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd E:/public/root/myFirstRepo
env -i "C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git" pull
```

However this seems to break git bash for windows:

> error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory

Ok, so lets try and use the git -C flag: explicity saying what folder to operate on.

```
#!/bin/sh
"C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git" -C "E:/public/root/myFirstRepo" pull
```

Still:

> fatal: Not a git repository: '.'

At this point im out of ideas. My question is basically: How to properly set up a git server post-recieve script in windows enviroment?

Comment: You already have a cloned repo at E:/public/root/myFirstRepo, don't you?

Comment: Yes and git pull works in that repo when running as my personal user

Comment: And where is your _Git Server bare repository folder_?

Comment: E:/public/custom/bonobo.git.server/Repositories/...

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting to do the same thing on a Windows 2012 instance.  After working on it for a while I was able to get the post-receive hook to update a local repository.  Assuming you have Bonobo Git server and Git installed, here are the steps.  I used the paths from the initial post.

1. Create the local repo with git clone http(s)://username:password#myserver/Bonobo.Git.Server/.git

you need to include a username and password so it's stored locally.  This will be necessary for the hook operations.  It's a bit of a security issue, but I assume this server won't routinely be accessed outside the admin.

2. Add the IIS_IUSRS account to the newly created  git repository.  Right click the directory and add the user account.  Give it write permission.  I actually gave full control.
3. Create the post-receive file (no extension) in the hooks directory for the repository.  Use the correct path to Git executable, not the Bonobo Git.

## !/Git/sh

cd E:\public\root\myFirstRepo\

"c:\Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git" --git-dir=E:\public\root\myFirstRepo\.git stash

"c:\Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core/git" --git-dir=E:\public\root\myFirstRepo\.git pull

There will be a few warning initially, but once you push files to the remote server, the hook script should update them accordingly.